# Swift 3.0 UiTableView inside scrollView ContainerView is not calling DidSelectRow (Twitter Profile)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

This is my first time on Stack asking a question.

I have this sample project I'm messing with -> https://github.com/spro/TwitterProfileClone

It's a clone of Twitter's Profile page.

The problem is when touching a cell, didSelectRow is NOT getting called. I have tried everything from delaying the scrollViews touches, to GestureTap recognizers but nothing has worked.

It would be a great help to point me in the right direction. I'm not pasting any code because you can take a look at the sample and see how to get didSelectRow to actually work.

Cheers!

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard go to ProfileViewController > Select tableView

Pass selection setting "No selection during editing" to "Single selection"

[image: Selection setting]

Comment: You're welcome. Then validate the answer if it has worked ;)